# Chrome skype extension gets attached to all 10 digit numbers in my report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome-extension

Currently I am working on showing data in reports for my portal in MVC. In my report, I have buyers ids which have 10 digits. So when I enable skype extension in my chrome browser then this gets attached to all my buyers id which have 10 digits due to which I am unable to filter the data corresponding those buyer ids.

Answer (score 0):

Skype Click to Call Plug in has default behavior to link numbers to phone format.
Currently You need to uninstall this plug in if it is a problem.

See link 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128583/skype-plugin-converts-user-reputation-and-badges-to-a-phone-number